# resource:memory error when trying to run an ECS task using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up CI with AWS ECS and docker. I use Codeship as a CI tool, but that should not really matter much.

I do the following steps in a shell script:

- build an image with my Dockerfile,
- push the image to ECS repository,
- push a task-definition.json to ECS `aws ecs register-task-definition --family postgraphile --cli-input-json file:///deploy/ecs-task-def.json --region us-east-2`
- run the ECS task `aws ecs run-task --task-definition postgraphile --cluster testcluster --region us-east-2`

Shell script runs successfully, however I see an error in output after I try to run my ECS task:

```
{
    "tasks": [],
    "failures": [
        {
            "arn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:99999999999:container-instance/050ab165-7669-45d5-8be7-d990cf4fff42",
            "reason": "RESOURCE:MEMORY"
        }
    ]
}
```

my `ecs-task-def.json`:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "postgraphile-container",
      "image": "999999999999.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/test-repository",
      "memory": 500,
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5000,
          "containerPort": 5000
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "volumes": [],
  "memory": "900",
  "cpu": "128",
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "family": "postgraphile",
  "taskRoleArn": ""
}
```

I think I already checked all the memory limits.. am I missing anything?

UPDATE:
After couple of reboots of ec2 instance I can finally run the ecs task with no errors. After running task several times, the error returns

Comment: In my case, this occurred because my EC2 instance had less memory than I had specified in my container. I was able to find the details in the Events tab in my service (ECS > Cluster > Service > Events).

Comment: Did you ever find out how to tell "aws ecs run-task" to run an instance on your cluster with enough memory to run the task?

Comment: yes, everything is ok with task definition. My problem was: I tried to run the task, when there already was a running task. So as i want to just restart a running task, I actually have to stop the running task and run it again using the same task definition

Comment: In my case, I wanted 8 Go so I wrote memory: 8000000, but the memory is in megabytes so I needed 8000 (7800 exactly).

Comment: @cklab thank you friend. i updated the EC2 instance type for one more small, but my elastic beanstalk application stopped working. so the reason was exactly the thing that you said: "my EC2 instance had less memory than I had specified in my container"... thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There are limited values accepted for CPU and memory. Check the docs for the supported values:

| CPU value | Memory value (MiB) |
| --- | --- |
| 256 (.25 vCPU) | 512 (0.5GB), 1024 (1GB), 2048 (2GB) |
| 512 (.5 vCPU) | 1024 (1GB), 2048 (2GB), 3072 (3GB), 4096 (4GB) |
| 1024 (1 vCPU) | 2048 (2GB), 3072 (3GB), 4096 (4GB), 5120 (5GB), 6144 (6GB), 7168 (7GB), 8192 (8GB) |
| 2048 (2 vCPU) | Between 4096 (4GB) and 16384 (16GB) in increments of 1024 (1GB) |
| 4096 (4 vCPU) | Between 8192 (8GB) and 30720 (30GB) in increments of 1024 (1GB) |

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-cpu-memory-error.html

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when deploying a service on an ECS cluster. Removing the service completely and then redeploying it afresh helped me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar error while deploying services to EC2 using docker. I was using putty not CLI. I ran command `docker images` to get the size of each image. I found total size was more than my EC2 instance storage. I increased the EC2 instance volume to 20GB (EC2-->Volume-->Modify volume). Issue was resolved. Later I faced issue again after multiple trial and error. This time, I found I had lot of unused images which got accumulated after multiple docker compose commands. I removed all the containers, volumes and images and memory error was resolved.